# Import error: cannot import name preprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pycharm, importerror

from sklearn while importing ensemble, model_selection, preprocessing.
It shows the Import error. (I am working on Pycharm)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "File path", line 4, in <module>
        from sklearn import ensemble, model_selection, preprocesing, tree
    ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocesing'
```

I have already installed `NumPy, SciPy, and scikit-learn`.

Currently, my interpreter is the virtual environment and I was reading somewhere that I should change the path. I am not able to do that ' since it says environment not empty' Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated

Comment: There's a typo there. It's  `preprocessing`, not `preprocesing`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because they are modules on their own. Try:

```
import sklearn.preprocessing
import sklearn.tree
import sklearn.ensemble
```

or

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me -

```
import sklearn.preprocessing as preprocessing
import sklearn.ensemble as ensemble
import sklearn.model_selection as ms
```

or you can import specific classes like this -

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```